# what are the various ways to fetch the properties from payload?

Tags: mule

What is the difference between reading the properties from payload. for example there is a property in the payload which is named as con_id. when i read this property like this #[payload.con_id] then it is coming as null. where as #[payload.'con_id'] is returning the value.

few other notations which i know of is #[payload['con_id']] or #[json:con_id]
which one should be used at which scenario? if there are any special cases to use any specific notation then please let me know the scenario also.

Also, what is the common notation that has to be used from a mule soft platform supported point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 3 any of those syntax are valid. Except the `json:` evaluator is for querying json documents where as the others are for querying maps/objects. Also the `json:` evaluator is deprecated in Mule 3 in favor of transforming to a map and using the MEL expressions below.

```
payload.property
payload.'property'
payload['property']
```

The reason the first fails in your case, is beacaue of the special character '_'. The underscore forces the field name to be wrapped in quotes.

Typically the . notation is preferred over the [''] as its shorter for accessing map fields. And then simply wrap property names in '' for any fields with special chars.

**Note** in Mule 4, you don't need to transform to a map/object first. Dataweave expression replace MEL as the expression language and allow you to directly query json or any type of payload without transforming to a map first.

Comment: first of all, Thanks Ryan! good to know the underlying reasons for the same. but why this some times work and some times doesn't on standalone environment? because i was never able to replicate on studio on my local environment. could you please share if there are any replication steps for the same.